# Windows .net Google.Apis call to InsertMediaUpload.Upload hangs and there is no timeout

Tags: google-app-engine

I am using the GoogleApis to upload documents to Google Drive using the InsertMediaUpload form the FilesResource namespace class and the Upload method. It is working well for me with the following exception:

After calling InsertMediaUpload, a browser window appears asking the user to log into their Google (usually Gmail) account. If the user simply closes the browser window instead of clicking on "Accept" or "Cancel" then the current process appears to be hung. I suppose there should a timeout of a minute or two so that if the user opts to not log in the current windows application will not simply hang and stop working indefinitely.

Thanks in advance for any help with this.

Comment: this isn't an appengine question.  You might want to retag it with more appropriate tags if you want an answer.